# How to make a FormSet JSON serializable?

Tags: json, django

I am trying to pass a formset as JSON data but i am getting `Object of type HabitFormFormSet is not JSON serializable`.

Why is that ?

my view:

```
def modal_view(request):
    HabitFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        Habit, extra=0, form=HabitModelForm)
    formset = HabitFormSet(
        request.POST,
        queryset=Habit.objects.filter(user=request.user),
    )
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        data = {"formset": formset}
        return JsonResponse(data)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

If I use a list of dictionaries i get `Object of type Habit is not JSON serializable`:

```
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        formlist = list()
        for form in formset:
            formlist.append(form.cleaned_data)
        data = {"formlist": formlist}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no default JSON serialization for custom classes.

You may want to add a, say, `to_json()` or `as_json()` (choose one) function to your `Habit` model, e.g.

```
def to_json(self):
    return {
        "id": self.id,
        "something": self.something,
    }
```

Then, make a list of the (newly saved) Habits:

```
data = {"new_habits": [form.instance.to_json() for form in formset if form.instance.id]}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-it `JSONEncoder` has a strategy to serialize each **python primitive type**, but he does not know how to serialize your custom types (especially instances of your custom classes).

You might write your own `JSONEncoder` subclass, and tell `JsonResponse` to use it